# How do "peer-port" settings work in Transmission (especially for VPN & port-forwarding-enabled false)?

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, bittorrent, transmission

I am wondering how the ***"peer-port"*** settings should be configured when **Transmission** (specifically `transmission-daemon`) is working together with a VPN service provider, for which I intend to enable *Port Forwarding*.

Assume for my situation that `"port-forwarding-enabled"` currently is `false`.

These are my more specific questions:

- Does Transmission only use one (1) `peer-port` at a time (e.g. 51413)? Does the amount of ***peer-ports*** in any way limit the amount of simultaneous incoming connections, or the amount of peers I seed to?
- If so – If I enable `peer-port-random`, will it still just use one (1) peer-port within the range `peer-port-random-low` and `peer-port-random-high` at one moment in time of running Transmission? Or will it use multiple of these ports simultaneously?
- Because I wish to use VPN Port Forwarding, is/are these the port(s) for which I should enable Port Forwarding for on my VPN service provider's website – without opening them in my LAN Firewalls?
- My understanding for my current situation is that I shall continue to have `port-forwarding-enabled` be `false` at all times to disallow uPnP and NAT-PMP protocols for a more secure approach – even if I enable Port Forwarding on my VPN provider's website, and should have the same port(s) as my designated ***peer-port*** range. Please confirm if that's correct?

---

*NB:* Peer Port parameters according to this [page](https://www.readynas.com/contributed/super-poussin/Transmission-Parameters.htm):

[image]